# Obtaining a desired average with a minimum constraint

Tags: mean, extreme-value, constraint

I have a database with two columns of interest, a weight $w_i$ and a proportion of something $p_i$. I want to create a new proportion, $p'_i$, that is derived from $p_i$, with two constraints :

- $p'_i$ must be at least 50%
- I have a target for the weighted average of $p'_i$ : $\sum w_ip'_i=\alpha$

By deriving them from $p_i$, I mean that my goal is to give a proportion for each unit. My calclations yield $p_i$. Nevertheless, another external constraint that I have, is that none of these $p_i$ should be inferior to 50%. So the $p'_i$ I want in the end must be close to $p_i$, I have to "tweak" them to obtain $p'_i$.
That is why my initial idea was to create 
$\tilde{p}_i=max(0.50,p_i)$, and then $p'_i=\tilde{p}_i*\cfrac{\alpha}{\sum w_i \tilde{p}_i}$. But by doing so, I had to reduce some of the $\tilde{p}_i=max(0.50,p_i)$ that I had set to 50%, therefore violating one of my need.

Is there a simple way to do both things simultaneously? Or at least in two times, as I guess I can repeat my process and it will converge in the end.

Comment: Your post is a little unclear. It sounds like $p_i$ itself is irrelevant to the discussion (otherwise you need to clarify what constraints it imposes - currently you suggest *none at all*), in which case you should just be talking about the "new proportion". I think you are asking us to come with a collection of proportions, each of which you want to be greater than 50%, and whose weighted average is some target value. Easy - make them all the target value (which must exceed 50% itself). Please clarify.

Comment: I tried to make it clearer.

Comment: Can you clarify the sense in which you mean close to?

Comment: I do not have any particular constraint. My $p_i$ are obtained by some "objective" parameters. But the "no proportion under 50%" is a posterior, "political" criterion. If you want a particular one you can take something like $min \sum w_i(p_i - p'_i)^2$

Comment: In fact I would say simplicity would be the primary criterion as it is supposed to be explained to people not that fluent in mathematics

Comment: Okay; thanks, at least that gives some kind of sense of the sort of solution that you might find useful

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should precisely formulate your problem as an optimization problem and then solve the optimization problem.

Let $\mathbf{p}$ be your initial vector and $\mathbf{q}$ be the vector you're trying to create.

My quick reading of it suggests the problem is something like:

\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}{*2{>{\displaystyle}r}}
 \mbox{minimize (over $\mathbf{q}$)} & \| \mathbf{p} - \mathbf{q} \| \\
 \mbox{subject to} & q_i \geq .5\\
&q_i \leq 1 \\
    &\sum_i w_i q_i = a \\
 \end{array}
\end{equation}

Where $\|\mathbf{p} - \mathbf{q}\|$ is the norm of vector $\mathbf{p} - \mathbf{q}$. You could experiment with different norms. If you use the [2-norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Norm.html), this is a [quadratic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) problem, and there are a plethora of software packages etc... to solve it.

You say $q_i$ is a proportion? So I added the constraint that it is less than or equal to 1.

Comment: I guess I can do something like that, but it is a bit heavy for those I am supposed to give it to.